# Getting the 983rd prime number instead of 1000th

Tags: python, function, primes

I have just started coding, and I don't seem to be getting it quite right. I would like some feedback on my program.

I am getting 7753 instead of 7919

```
primes = []
sk     = [] # list for all None values

def primtal(a):
    if ((2 ** a) - 2) % a == 0:
        return a

t = 2
while len(primes) < 1001:
    kand = primtal(t)
    if kand == None:
       sk.append(kand)
    else:
        primt = kand 
        primes.append(primt)
    t = t + 1

print primes[1000]
```

Comment: Is the check `((2**a)-2) % a == 0` checking whether a number is prime?  I've not seen that one before...

Comment: As @mgilson noted, [pseudoprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) like 341 == 11*31 will cause problems for your `primtal`.  (Plus remember that `primes[1000]` is the 1001th prime..)

Comment: @mgilson it seems to work rather...

Comment: Please can you give us a link to the algorithm you're using? Like `mgilson` I haven't seen that one before. Also, the values of your variables `sk` and `primt` seem to be pointless as they are never used. `sk` is just an array of `None` values and `primt` is just a copy of `kand`.

Comment: @Zizouz212 it's true that for any prime p for all k < p, k^(p-1) = 1 (mod p), but all non-primes satisfy that property for some values of k, and some (carmichael numbers) satisfy it for all k despite not being prime.

Comment: What does `sk` do here? Even with the comment it's not clear. Isn't this basically just `if kand is None: pass` ?

Comment: @mgilson: This is a particularly inefficient version of the [Fermat Pseudoprime test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) to the base 2.

Comment: Ye, primt was unecessary and sk i used as a trashbin to put all kands that returned None so the primes array would only house primenumbers. But that was before i knew of ": pass"

the algorithm i found in some other question here on stackoverflow, i believe, a couple of weeks ago, dunno which one though